# Update problem via OLE DB provider MSDASQL - Linked Server

Tags: mysql, sql, oledb, linked-server

i am trying to update table via OLE DB provider MSDASQL for a linked server.

Connection is working, select statments work without problems. Update also worked until now.

Linked Server: MYSQL DB - update via MYSQL workbench works fine

But now i get the following error:

> The OLE DB provider "MSDASQL" for linked server "xxx" could not UPDATE
> table "[xxx]...[yyy.zzz]". [SQLSTATE 42000] (Error 7343) OLE DB
> provider "MSDASQL" for linked server "xxx" returned message
> "[MySQL][ODBC 8.0(w) Driver][mysqld-5.7.38-google-log]You have an
> error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your
> MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '.zzz SET
> trn_state=? WHERE check=? AND check_pos=? AND checkopen_time=' at line
> 1". [SQLSTATE 01000] (Error 7412). The step failed.

My update statement:

```
update [xxx]...[yyy.zzz]
set trn_state = 1
where trn_state = 0
```

And yes, it is the first line of the statement - i don't know why the error is referencing things that are not in the statement.

Error message does not match my statement - why ?

Whats the reason ? What am I doing wrong ?

Error in provider options or linked server properties ? Can it be a wrong setting on the other side ?

Comment: Square brackets are out of MySQL syntax, SQL Server (MS SQL) uses them...

Comment: the sql looks correct.  it is the config of the linked server and/or MSDASQL provider.  set both RPC options to True for the linked server options.  in the properties of the provider, check nested queries, allow inprocess and level zero only

Comment: the statement ist correct. updated the config for the linked server, for the provider options only these 3 options ? no dynamic parameter ? no non transacted updates and no supports 'like' operator ?

Comment: same error. Could it be the index on the mysql table ?